# How to avoid quotes while inserting JSON in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have data which has to be inserted in mongodb collection but the fields should not have quotes after they get inserted.
This is what I am doing:

```
    var newStep = {
        start : startvalue,
        end : endvalue
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newStep,
        url: '/addstep',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    }).done(function( data ) {
            $.each(data, function(){
                      //do something
            });
    });
```

After the insert is over.
The data looks like this:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56348aa4962428f243c85b26"), 
"start" : "13.0464655",
"end" : "77.59167"
}
```

I want it look like this

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56348aa4962428f243c85b26"), 
"start" : 13.0464655,
"end" : 77.59167
}
```

How to avoid the quotes around the fields start and end. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: I dont know if this affects anything, but this is my route:

```
router.post('/addStep', function(req, res) {
var db = req.db;

var start = req.body.start;
var end = req.body.end;

var collection = db.get('steplist');

collection.update(
    {
            //some conditions
    },
    {
            $setOnInsert: req.body
    },
    {
            "upsert": true
    }, function(err, result){
    res.send(
        (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert startValue and endValue to float type before inserting them.

```
var newStep = {
    start : parseFloat(startValue),
    end : parseFloat(endValue)
}
```

That would insert them as float instead of string.